# Adding data elements to payload and convert to JSON - for Kafka producer consumer

Tags: python, json, apache-kafka

I am trying to create below payload and send from kakfa producer with msg_data as the topic. It works fine. However I want to add more data fields apart from RSSI, which I am unable to.

**Payload trying to send**

```
msg_data ="""\
"data": {
       "RSSI": %.1f
     }
   }
}"""
```

**Jason output**

```
for counter in range(0, numMsgs):
  # Generate a random floating point number
    randomRSSI = random.uniform(0.0, 40.0)
    if counter == numMsgs - 1:
    print imsg_data % (randomRSSI)
```

**Trying to do something like below which doesn't work**

```
  msg_data ="""\
    "data": {
           "RSSI": %.1f,
           "CPU" : %.1f
         }
       }
    }"""
```

Comment: do you have parsing issues or while publishing in kafka topic?

Comment: I am using issues creating JSON format for it. how does that print imsg_data get formed with other parameter ? I tried few things my python code doesnt compile

Comment: Don't use a string. Just create a dictionary and `json.dumps` it. If your code doesn't "compile", please show the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out its simple - I was using two % % for each one below command works but.

```
print iotmsg_data % ((randomRSSI), (CPUval))
```